# RVM Ruby Abort Trap Segmentation fault, switching directories and doing rvm use ree works

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm, mysql2

I have a very very weird problem. My rvm setup is ruby enterprise edition (ree 2011-02-18 patchlevel 334), it is set to be the default (rvm use ree --default). I am on rvm 1.6.13 and on a rails 3 project. 
Now: once i try to run rails s, rails c, or any rake command I get the following:

```
/Users/florianvallen/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@flats/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.4.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03

Abort trap
```

which ruby is: `~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby`

The weird thing is that i can resolve that with `rvm use ree`
which tells me `Using /Users/florianvallen/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03`

After that everything works. Now, one might think that putting `rvm use ree` in your ~/.profile would at least solve the problem, but when i switch directories with `cd ..` and enter the rails project again, I get the same thing, `[Bug] Segmentation fault...`

Does anyone have an idea why this is like that?

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been solved as the installed gems werent in the correct gemset. weirdly the gemset has not been created when switching to the directory even though it has been defined by the .rvmrc in that directory.
Removing and installing the gemset again has solved the issue.

Comment: this woked for me too.  So to recap:   
    `rvm gemset delete <gemsetname>`  
    `rvm gemset create <gemsetname>`  
    `rvm use @<gemsetname>`  
    `bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the gems you installed with your rails project were installed under ree?  The gems have C extensions which are dependent on your ruby version which is probably your problem.  Remove all of your gems and rebundle/reinstall them under rvm ree.